# PHP exp() not working. Getting an infinite number

Tags: php

**Javascript:** var random = Math.exp(Math.random() * Math.log(100 - 10 + 10)) + 10;

*Edit: + 10 inside the log function was a typo*.

**Attempt for a PHP Equivalent:** $random = exp(rand() * log(100 - 10 + 10)) + 10;

The latter returns false, where the first returns a number. The problem is definately the exponent function that behaves differently.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why 100-10+10? It is not the same as 100 ?

Comment: @Amarnasan - Isn't it? Simple integer arithmetic - https://3v4l.org/That2

Comment: @MarkBaker based on how Math.random works  Math.random() * (max - min) + min

Comment: That is the formula in JS to set up a minimum and maximum value because (max - min) is calculated first plus min

Comment: @MarkBaker Are you been cheeky? Why use Math.log(100-10+10) when it is easier to use Math.log(100) ?

Comment: @Amarnasan ya sorry about that. The result in there is the same indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Math.random returns a number between 0 and 1.

rand() return a big integer. That's where the infinite comes from.

**Edit**

Documentation for [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) and [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

You can change your code as follows to overcome this:

```
$random = exp((rand(1, 1000)/1000) * log(100 - 10 + 10)) + 10;
```

Comment: exp(rand() * 2) should generate a random number between 0 and 2

Comment: @Asperger - In PHP, __rand(0,1) * 2__ returns a random number between __0__ and __2__ (though you could more easily do `rand(0,2)`); __rand() * 2__ returns a random number between __0__ and __2 * PHP_INT_MAX__

Comment: @MarkBaker so would this work exp(rand(10, log(100)))?

Comment: @Asperger - Not exactly as you might expect, because if you pass arguments to rand() they should be __integer__ arguments..... log(100) is 4.6051701859881, which isn't an integer..... though it will be cast to an integer inside the rand() function, using standard PHP casting rules

Comment: @Asperger - Though in practical terms, it will give a random integer value between 4 and 10

Comment: @MarkBaker I could use a rounding function but that might destroy how my entire program works